# Local data type definitions

Tags: haskell, syntax, state-machine, algebraic-data-types

Implementing finite state automata in Haskell, I'd like to do this:

```
zigzag :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
zigzag low upp = fsa Incr low

   where
      data State = Incr | Decr

      fsa :: State -> Int -> [Int]
      fsa state n
         = n : case state of
                  Incr | n < upp   -> fsa Incr (n + 1)
                       | otherwise -> fsa Decr (n - 1)

                  Decr | n > low   -> fsa Decr (n - 1)
                       | otherwise -> fsa Incr (n + 1)
```

But I can't:

```
error: parse error on input ‘data’
```

Is there a better way than to separate the `State` definition from `zigzag`?

---

I wouldn't want to encode state identifiers implicitly in terms of booleans or numbers if I can use an explicit enumeration or data type. Local function definition is meant to enable modularity, to protect the integrity of descriptive namespaces from single-relation/use clutter. I don't understand why data definitions in that respect should be treated differently.

Comment: Local data type definitions are unsupported. You have to lift them to the top level of the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put `data` definitions locally, only at the top level. However you could use a `Bool` and `if` rather than a custom data type and `case`.

Alternatively, you can put the function and data type in their own module if you don't want to export the `data` type.

It [has been proposed](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4k84go/data_declarations_in_where_statements/) to include this feature, but it isn't a priority for some reason. I guess generally people view types as high-level protocols between top-level functions, not typically between `where`-level functions.

Comment: I wouldn't want to encode state identifiers implicitly in terms of booleans or numbers if I can use an explicit enumeration or data type. *Local* function definition is meant to enable modularity, to protect the integrity of descriptive namespaces from single-relation/use clutter. I don't understand why `data` definitions in that respect should be treated differently.